# The following equation has several solutions $2x+3y=73$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given  $2x+3y=73$ 
so we know that the GCD of these is 1 so i do the Euclidean algorithm
, i got that  $2(3t-73)+3(73+2t)=73$.

now if  x,y is Rational how many solutions?

if  x,y is Integers how many solutions?

if  x,y is Natural how many solutions?

this question made me confused because i thought if i have gcd = c so it means

that the diofant equation has infinite solution.

thank you guys.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "i don't understand, if the gcd=c that means the equation have infinite solutions."  Please try to clarify what you are asking.  Also, give your thoughts on all these questions.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: And what do you think about these questions?  How many solutions in rationals has the equation, for example?  This isn't a site where you can post your homework for other people to do for you.  If you show us what you are trying to do, and where you are getting stuck, we'll be glad to help you.

Comment: i will pay attention to this in the future , thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the equation to get
$$y=\frac{73-2x}{3}.$$
This shows that for every rational $x$ there is a rational $y$ satisfying the equation. So there are infinitely many solutions in the rational numbers.

This also shows that $y$ is an integer if and only if $x$ is an integer of the form $3n+2$. So there are also infinitely solutions in the integers.

This also shows that if $y$ is a natural number then $73-2x\geq0$ and so $x\leq\frac{73}{2}$. This shows that there are only finitely many solutions in the natural numbers, and it is not hard to list them all.

Answer (score 2):

If $2x + 3y = 73$ then $3y = 73 - 2x$ so that $$y = \frac{73 - 2x}{3}.$$ For any rational value of $x$, $$y = \frac{73 - 2x}{3}$$ is a rational number satisfying $2x + 3y = 73$ so there are a countably infinite number of rational solutions.

For integers, note that if $x = -1$ and $y = 1$ then $2x + 3y = 1$. Multiplying by 73, $x= -73$ and $y = 73$ satisfies $2x + 3y = 73$. Finally, for any $n$, $x = -73 + 3n$, $y = 73 - 2n$ satisfy $2x + 3y = 2(-73 + 3n) + 3(73 - 2n) = 73 + 6n - 6n = 73.$

There are a countably infinite number of integer solutions.